# how to call a function or exported object from another class?

Tags: node.js

It might seems a duplicated question but before this i searched web and found several pages that explain how to `export` a simple object like a variable in **nodejs** but actually they didn't answer my question.

I have a class **callAPI.js** that get response in JSON format from an API ([refrence](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/http-js/)):

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const APIURL = "http://example.com/api/hairdress";
var id = 0;

const GetData = async APIURL => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(APIURL + `/GetHairdressReservableTimes/${id}`);
        const JSONResponse = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {

    }
}

module.exports.DataResponse = GetData(id);
```

in main class **app.js** i call it inside a function like this:

```
const SECONDAPI = require("./callAPI");
function SendSelectedTime(selectedID) {
    var res = "";
    try {
        const temp = SECONDAPI.DataResponse(selectedID);
        console.log("DATA:" + temp);

        if (temp.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                const element = temp[i];
                res += element + "\n";
            }
        }
        else {
            res = "oops, something went wrong. ☹️";
        }

    } catch (error) {

    }
    return res;
}

var serviceResponse=SendSelectedTime(1);
```

the problem is `temp` variable is always undefined! although I'm not sure that `module.exports.DataResponse = GetData(id);` section is correct or not?!.

I'm trying to call `callAPI` class every where i needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted three things:

1. Your arrow function does not define the `id` argument. (see MDN docs for arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))
2. You are missing the `return` statement in your `GetData` function.
3. The `GetData` function is `async` so you have to `await` for the return value. (see MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function))

Here is your `callAPI.js` with the fixes:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const APIURL = "http://example.com/api/hairdress";

const GetData = async (id) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(APIURL + `/GetHairdressReservableTimes/${id}`);
        const JSONResponse = await response.json();
        return JSONResponse;
    } catch (error) {

    }
}

module.exports.DataResponse = GetData(id);
```

And `app.js`: (Note that i made `SendSelectedTime` async)

```js
const SECONDAPI = require("./callAPI");
async function SendSelectedTime(selectedID) {
    var res = "";
    try {
        const temp = await SECONDAPI.DataResponse(selectedID);
        console.log("DATA:" + temp);

        if (temp.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                const element = temp[i];
                res += element + "\n";
            }
        }
        else {
            res = "oops, something went wrong. ☹️";
        }

    } catch (error) {

    }
    return res;
}

var serviceResponse=SendSelectedTime(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I changed the code according to your answer but i get undefined result for `temp` on `const temp = await SECONDAPI.DataResponse(selectedID);`